# What's the difference between "Some time", "Sometime" and "Sometimes"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

I have a question.

What is the difference between **Some time**, **Sometime** and **Sometimes**

When it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some time*

When *some time* is two words, it refers to a length of time. Usually/it mostly means “a long time.”

> For some time, humans have known that the earth revolves around the
>   sun.

*Sometime*: Adverb

When you use *sometime* as an adverb, it refers to an unspecified point in time. It doesn’t refer to a span of time, that is what *some time* is for.

> I’ll get around to finishing that rug cleaning sometime.

*Sometimes*: One Word

*Sometimes* is a one-word adverb that means “occasionally” or “now and then.”

> Sometimes I just can't figure out what that person is saying.

Comment: Are the sections in quote blocks quoted from somewhere? If so, could you please cite the source?  Please see: [How to reference material written by others](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: no, I was told to use blockquote to enhance my answer (many cooks here!) I said I thought it was for quoted material but was told the highlighting made answers easier to read.

Comment: In this answer, it would make sense to put the three example sentences in block quotes.  The yellow boxes tell the reader that the material is quoted, so if that is not the case, it doesn't make sense to use blockquote syntax.

Comment: @snailplane -- is this better? Or was this not what you meant? Feel free to fix it for me.

Comment: Yes, looks good :-)